# Modify this find function to accommodate more than one value

Tags: jquery, find

This function allows users to filter products by color (using `data-attributes`). How can I modify it to accommodate more than one value?

I'd like the function to return all items matching any of the data-attribute's values, and revert to the stricter criteria of the remaining filters when one of the filters is removed (by either unchecking the specific value or all color values). I've posted a fiddle with a simple example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/21/. The fiddle currently has the `data-attributes` inside `<li>` tags, but I'd like to use checkboxes in order to allow for multiple selections.

**Edit -** Products can have more than value in data-color *(i.e. Black , White)* indicating that it's available in either color, and can be multi-colored *(i.e. Black & White)*.

I'm assuming that instead of *`$(this).data('color')`* I should use something like *`$('input:checkbox:checked').data('color')`* , but I'm not sure how to structure it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        $('#attributes-Colors').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if (attrColor == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } else {
            $('#content').find('li:not([data-color="' + attrColor + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('[data-color ~="' + attrColor + '"]').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd try keeping an array of the values. On click, check if in the array and if so, remove it, if not add it. Then iterate through the values and show the matching elements.

Comment: @j08691 - That makes a lot of sense :-) Would you mind showing me the code for doing that?

Comment: @j08691 - I'm assuming that instead of $(this).data('color'); I should use something like $('input:checkbox:checked').data('color');, but I'm not sure how to structure it correctly

Comment: would you mind a solution using classes on the <li> elements?

Comment: I suggested classes because you might have more than one color associated with each element and you can use multiple classes on elements

Comment: Does the way you store the data in the data attribute matter? You have one like `Blue , Red` and another like `Black & White`.

Comment: @j08691 - Black & White refers to a multi-colored item, vs. Black , White which would refer to an item that's available in either Black or White

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/zJVZf/1/

Comment: @w3jimmy - Not quite :-( The fiddle you posted only allows selecting one color at a time. I'd like to be able to select several colors at the same time (i.e. Gray, Blue)

Comment: @w3jimmy - :-D But now I understood what you were asking me about classes ;-) I think I'm better off using data-attributes with this because it's being used for several different php queries and both js & php functions. This is a very simplified example, but there are going to be bet. 10-100 data-attributes (with bet. 5 - 50 values per attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/20/

I didn't add any handling for the "all colors" link, but that should be easy enough to do

```
    var selected = [];
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrColor), 1);
        } else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrColor);
        }
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function (index, item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-color ~="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The basic idea is to keep an array of the selected colors and any time one of your color buttons is clicked, you will hide all the items and then reshow those that match all the colors in your `selected` array.

For the `all colors` you can simply add some extra logic to blank all the others and make all you items visible.

Comment: That's perfect :-D One question - Would you mind showing me how to use it when I'm filtering by several data-attributes? I combined it with the code for another data-attribute http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/29/, but this function is a lot more sophisticated than the one I wrote ;-)

Comment: It's probably unimportant, but I figured I should let you know that I removed 'return false;' in order to allow the checkboxes to accept input

Comment: I ran into one hiccup - How can I get it to revert to showing all the items when all the filters are removed?

Comment: @ChayaCooper: Just add a check to see if `selected` is empty, if it is, then do `$("#content").find("*").show()`